# newline in javafx fxml or css

Tags: javafx, fxml, javafx-css

I'm new to javafx (and pretty much programming in general) and am trying to add \n characters to my fxml file. I've tried the text="${'10\nquestions'}" method as a test but I get can't resolve symbol '10\nquestions'. Learning how to put \n characters would be helpful but my actual problem comes from the Label fx:id questionText in quiz.fxml

> quiz.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane fx:controller="app.java.controllers.QuizController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <left>
    <VBox fx:id="quizLeft">
        <Label text="Java" />
        <Label fx:id="numberOfQuestions" />
        <Label fx:id="score" />
        <Label text="Time taken: 2:34" />
    </VBox>
  </left>
  <center>
    <VBox id="quizCenter">
        <VBox id="questionLabel">
            <Label fx:id="questionNumber" />
            <Label fx:id="questionText" />
        </VBox>

        <RadioButton fx:id="option1" >
            <toggleGroup>
                <ToggleGroup fx:id="answerList" />
            </toggleGroup>
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton fx:id="option2" toggleGroup="$answerList" />
        <RadioButton fx:id="option3" toggleGroup="$answerList" />
        <RadioButton fx:id="option4" toggleGroup="$answerList" />
        <StackPane id="submitButton">
            <Button fx:id="submitAnswerButton" text="Submit" onAction="#submitAnswerButton"/>
        </StackPane>
        <Button text="test" onAction="#printQuestions"/>
        <Button fx:id="homeButton" text="home" onAction="#backToWelcome"/>
    </VBox>
  </center>

</BorderPane>
```

currently, if a question is too long I get this.
[UI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Colip.png)

that question field that runs too long is connected to questionTextLabel which is populated from a mock db of Questions. How can I get questions that are too long to wrap to multiline. I've tried multiple things with the css as well, like messing around with -fx-text-overrun. Here are the css and controller classes as well. You can also see my project structure and other class in the img provided above.

```
/*quiz.css*/

.root{
  -fx-background-color: #1e349c;
}

#quizLeft{
  -fx-background-color: #9c0e7c;
  -fx-alignment: center;
  -fx-spacing: 10px;

  -fx-min-width: 300px;
}

.label{
  -fx-text-fill: #fea2ff;
  -fx-font-weight: bold;
  -fx-font-size: 30px;
}

#quizCenter{
  -fx-alignment: center;
}

#questionLabel{
  -fx-padding: 70px;
  -fx-alignment: center;
}

/*#questionText{*/
/*    !*-fx-text-overrun: ;*!*/
/*}*/

.radio-button{
  -fx-font-size: 30px;
  -fx-text-fill: yellow;
  -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

#submitButton{
  -fx-padding: 60px;
  -fx-font-size: 30px;
}

package app.java.controllers;

import app.java.dao.Question;
import app.java.services.SceneBuilder;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class QuizController extends Controller implements Initializable {

@FXML
Button submitAnswerButton;
@FXML
Label questionNumber;
@FXML
Label questionText;
@FXML
RadioButton option1;
@FXML
RadioButton option2;
@FXML
RadioButton option3;
@FXML
RadioButton option4;
@FXML
Button homeButton;
@FXML
Label score;
@FXML
Label numberOfQuestions;
@FXML
ToggleGroup answerList;

Question currentQuestion;
int correctAnswers;
int questionsAnswered;
int currentQuestionNumber;
List<Question> quizList;
SceneBuilder sb;

public void backToWelcome() throws Exception{
    sb.setNewScene(homeButton, "welcome");
}

public void submitAnswerButton() throws Exception{
    updateScore();
    if(questionsAnswered == quizList.size()){
        // games over
        sb.setNewSceneWithParameters(submitAnswerButton, "endOfQuiz", score);

    } else {
        // continue to next question
        currentQuestionNumber++;
        currentQuestion = quizList.get(currentQuestionNumber);
        setQuestionNumber(currentQuestionNumber);
        setQuestionText(currentQuestion.getQuery());
        setChoices(currentQuestion.getAnswers());
    }
}

public void setQuestionNumber(int questionNumber){
    this.questionNumber.setText("Question #" + (questionNumber + 1));
}

public Question getQuestionFromList(int nextQuestion){
    return quizList.get(nextQuestion);
}

public void setQuestionText(String questionText){
    this.questionText.setText(questionText);
}

public void setChoices(List<String> choices){
    option1.setText(choices.get(0));
    option2.setText(choices.get(1));
    option3.setText(choices.get(2));
    option4.setText(choices.get(3));
}

public boolean checkAnswer(String correctAnswer, String userGuess){
    return correctAnswer.equals(userGuess);
}

public void updateScore(){
    RadioButton selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton) answerList.getSelectedToggle();
    boolean isCorrect = checkAnswer(currentQuestion.getCorrectAnswer(), selectedRadioButton.getText());
    if(isCorrect){
        correctAnswers++;
    }
    questionsAnswered++;
    setScore();
}

public void printQuestions(){
    quizList.forEach(System.out::println);
}

public void setScore(){
    score.setText(correctAnswers + " correct out of " + questionsAnswered);
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    sb = new SceneBuilder();
    currentQuestionNumber = 0;
    questionsAnswered = 0;
    correctAnswers = 0;
    setScore();

}

@Override
public void initData(Object parameter) {
    this.quizList = (List<Question>)parameter;

    // Set first question
    currentQuestion = getQuestionFromList(currentQuestionNumber);
    setQuestionNumber(currentQuestionNumber);
    setQuestionText(currentQuestion.getQuery());
    setChoices(currentQuestion.getAnswers());
    this.numberOfQuestions.setText(quizList.size() + " questions");
}
}
```

Any help and advice I could get would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

edit:
I know SceneBuilder can do a lot of things for me but since this is my first try at it, I wanna write it myself so I know how to do it manually.

Comment: Check out the [`Labeled#wrapText`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#wrapTextProperty) property. Note that `Label` inherits from `Labeled` and thus inherits all its properties.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you!!!!! got any tips on the '\n' in fxml?

Comment: An FXML file is, at its core, just an XML file. Using either `&#10;` or `&#xA;` (note that `A` in hexadecimal is `10` in decimal) should work for you.